# Как должен выглядеть запрос в данном случае

Tags: php

В цикле вывожу все наименования фирм из таблицы companyname. Хочу внутри этой таблицы вывести сумму полей из таблицы gtable таким образом

```
<?php $query=mysqli_query( "SELECT SUM(salary) FROM gtable WHERE kid = $row5['id']"); $sum=mysqli_result($query,0); echo $sum; ?>
```

Пишет

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in ...

Как правильно составить запрос в данном случае. Дело в том что первый столбец таблицы (название фирмы) берется из другой таблицы mysql а вторые столбцы таблицы должны выводить сумму стобцов совсем из другой таблицы ? вообще можно ли такое ?

Comment: Тут ошибка PHP-ашная, к запросу отношения не имеющая. но вызов sql-запроса в цикле настораживает, такого происходить не должно. Скорее всего вам надо объединить данный запрос с тем, на основе которого идет цикл и получить все нужные данные в одном запросе. вам понадобится один JOIN и один GROUP BY

Comment: И да, _никогда_ не подставляйте никакие переменные непосредственно в текст запроса, используйте привязку переменных. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
$db = new mysqli(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT SUM(salary) FROM gtable WHERE kid = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $row5['id']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$sum = $result->fetch_field();
```

Comment: После WHERE kid = каким образом указать $row5['id'] ?

Comment: @AlexStassov следующую строку смотрите. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое !

Comment: а как вывести суммированные цифры на экран. Делаю так while ($sum = $result->fetch_field()) { 
     printf("Имя:         %s\n", $sum->name); } он выводит мне вот это Имя: SUM(salary)

Comment: rjhdby, подскажите пожалуйста если Вам не трудно

Comment: @AlexStassov этот SQL-запрос возвращает только одно значение, а именно сумму всех `salary` для одного конкретного `kid`. Соответственно запихивать `$result->fetch_field()` в цикл смысле не имеет никакого. Вам нужно либо запихнуть в цикл перебор ID-шников, для каждого делать `$stmt->ececute()`  и печать, либо, как советовал Mike, изменить SQL-запрос, чтобы он возвращал все необходимые вам данные за раз

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $query=mysqli_query( "SELECT SUM(salary) AS `sum` FROM gtable WHERE kid = $row5['id'] LIMIT 1;");
  $sum=mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
  echo $sum['sum'];
 ?>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ но всё равно выдает ошибку (

Comment: ошибку в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: как минимум вы не указали в каком соединении будет выполняться запрос

Comment: Странно, у кого поднялась рука дать балл за эту неграмотную ерунду?

Comment: Это ты сейчас про что говоришь ?